# Does CAS Maple use a scripting language for algorithms inside packages?

Tags: maple

Does Maple use a scripting language for algorithms inside packages,
like Student[LinearAlgebra]?
What really does command for loading a package, like this:

```
with(Student[LinearAlgebra]):
```

Answer (score 2):

The first of your two questions seems to be pretty similar to asking how Maple commands generally work, which is pretty broad so I'll just give a summary.

Question 1)

Maple is an [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language). Commands from its `Student[LinearAlgebra]` package are written in the Maple language, and stored by Maple in a so-called Maple Library archive (a file with filename extension `.mla`).

You can see and inspect most of the source of those package's exported commands using the Maple commands `showstat` (or `print`, when `interface(verboseproc)` is high enough). Note that the source of most of these commands involves calls to other, internal routines in the package (most of which in turn are written in the Maple language).

Many of the computational commands in the `Student[LinearAlgebra]` package  involve not much more than to calls to the `LinearAlgebra` package. Try these Maple commands, as examples:

```
showstat(Student:-LinearAlgebra:-ReducedRowEchelonForm);

showstat(:-LinearAlgebra:-ReducedRowEchelonForm);

showstat(:-LinearAlgebra:-LUDecomposition);
```

The `Student[LinearAlgebra]` package also has some visualization commands, for plotting. Eg,

```
showstat(Student:-LinearAlgebra:-EigenPlot);
```

And it also has some commands which launch interactive applets (or "Tutors", which are written using Maple code from its `Maplets` package which generate Java popup applets). Eg,

```
showstat(Student:-LinearAlgebra:-GaussianEliminationTutor);
```

The `showstat` command displays line numbers for the source. To see it without line numbers, and with syntax-highlighting and indentation, try this,

```
 interface(verboseproc=3):
 print(:-LinearAlgebra:-LUDecomposition);
```

You can write your own procedures (commands) in Maple, to compute whatever you want, and you can even save them to your own Library archive(s) for re-use later on. But a large portion of Maple is the set of thousands of procedures that have already been developed and are available to you.

If you want to know more then you should be more specific about what you're asking, I think.

Reading the User Manual (and, if you need more information, the Programming Guide) is also a good idea. You can access both from within Maple's Help.

Question 2)

When you issue the command,

```
with(Student[LinearAlgebra]):
```

Maple rebinds the names of the exports (commands intended for use directly by the user) from their long-form name to the short-form name. The effect is that you can then use the commands with less manual typing on the keyboard. This act of "loading" the package may also result in some additions being made to the context-sensitive menus (what pops up when you right-click on a Matrix, say).

Even if you don't "load the package" using the `with` command you can still use the commands from the package. For example, if M is a Matrix then you can always call,

```
Student:-LinearAlgebra:-Rank( M );
```

or

```
Student[LinearAlgebra][Rank]( M );
```

even if you haven't called `with(Student[LinearAlgebra])` beforehand. But once you've executed,

```
with(Student[LinearAlgebra]):
```

then you can use the much shorter syntax,

```
Rank( M );
```